# Read h264 frames

Tags: h.264, video-capture, video-processing

I am trying to read a network video stream encoded in h264 and I need to read the actual frames of it.
I am writing my code in c# but obviously can also read in c++.

I tried using ffmpeg, and I got some issues using it that I can't seem to get a grip on, it might be connected to using mixed (managed/unmanaged) code together, or something else, but although I am positive the code is right It won't work and I want to see if I can get what I want from other libraries.

I tried Vlc, but I get around 2 seconds delay from the video, which isn't good for me, I tried changing the cache setting, but it won't do the trick.

What other libraries are there that I can try? I found Impleo which is possible, but ain't free.

Thanks!

Comment: Try narrowing the focus a bit. If you tried ffmpeg and had problems, post what you tried. As asked this question is probably too broad.

Comment: is it raw h264, or is it in a container/protocol?

Comment: As theB said, please post your ffmpeg code.